# Debug Error - abort() has been called (gcz2tga)

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Complete C++/C newbie here. I recompiled gcz2tga (I did not make this code, just found it on the webs) into a debug .exe file using Visual Studio 2019. Everything works well until it gets to "split_images" and then the program spits out this error:

> Debug Error!
>
> Program: C:\Users\Harrison\source\repos\gcz2tga\Debug\gcz2tga.exe
>
> abort() has been called
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application)

When I hit Retry, the program closes. The code is set up like this:

```
/* gcz2tga.c: Slice up a directory full of GCZ (texture) files into TGA files.
 *
 * Credit goes to afwefwe for reverse-engineering the texture format 
 * and LZSS compression */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Assuming x86, usual endian crap is not accounted for */
typedef unsigned char u8_t;
typedef unsigned short u16_t;
typedef unsigned int u32_t;

struct image
{
    unsigned int width, height;
    u8_t *planes;
};

struct clip
{
    short x, y, w, h;
};

static u16_t swab16(u16_t in)
{
    /* GC headers are big-endian */
    return ((in & 0xFF) << 8) | (in >> 8);
}

static void unpack_gc(struct image *out, u8_t *in, size_t out_sz)
{
    unsigned int npixels;
    unsigned int i; 
    unsigned int j; 
    u16_t *pixels; 
    u16_t *pheight; 
    u16_t *pwidth;
    u16_t *pmagic;
    u16_t pixel;

    pmagic = (u16_t *) in;
    pheight = (u16_t *) (in + 14);
    pwidth = (u16_t *) (in + 12);

    if (*pmagic != 0x4347) {
        fprintf(stderr, "(FAIL: Invalid header)\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Set up output image struct */
    in += 24;
    out->width = swab16(*pwidth);
    out->height = swab16(*pheight);
    out->planes = malloc(out->width * out->height * 4);

    /* Clamp W/H (don't know why this is necessary but it is) */
    out->width = out->width > 1024 ? 1024 : out->width;
    out->height = out->height > 1024 ? 1024 : out->height;

    fprintf(stderr, "(%dx%d)", out->width, out->height);

    /* Unpack pixels */
    pixels = (u16_t *) in;
    npixels = out->width * out->height;

    if (out_sz > npixels * 4) {
        /* Deep image (i.e. 32-bit) */
        memcpy(out->planes, pixels, npixels * 4);
    } else {
    /* Shallow image (i.e. 16-bit) */
        for (i = 0, j = 0 ; i < npixels ; i++) {
            pixel = pixels[i];
            out->planes[j++] = ((pixel      ) & 0x1F)  << 3; /* B */
            out->planes[j++] = ((pixel >>  5) & 0x1F)  << 3; /* G */
            out->planes[j++] = ((pixel >> 10)       )  << 3; /* R */
            out->planes[j++] = pixel & 0x8000 ? 0xFF : 0x00; /* A */
        }
    }
}

static u8_t *expand_lzss(u8_t *lzss, size_t *pout_sz)
{
    static u8_t ring[0x1000];
    unsigned int ring_pos = 0x0FEE; 
    unsigned int chunk_offset; 
    unsigned int chunk_length; 
    u32_t control_word = 1;
    size_t length;
    u8_t cmd1; 
    u8_t cmd2;
    u8_t *out; 
    u8_t *pos; 
    u8_t *in; 

    /* Header = 32 bit unpacked file length */
    length = *((u32_t *) lzss);
    *pout_sz = length;

    if (length > 8000000) {
        fprintf(stderr, "(FAIL: Unreasonably large expanded size %d)\n", 
            length);

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    out = malloc(length * 2); /* Seems to overrun */
    pos = out;
    in = lzss + 4;

    while (length > 0) {
        if (control_word == 1) {
            /* Read a control byte */
            control_word = 0x100 | *in++;
        }

        /* Decode a byte according to the current control byte bit */
        if (control_word & 1) {
            /* Straight copy */
            *pos++ = *in;
            ring[ring_pos] = *in++;

            ring_pos = (ring_pos + 1) % 0x1000;
            length--;
        } else {
            /* Reference to data in ring buffer */
            cmd1 = *in++;
            cmd2 = *in++;

            chunk_length = (cmd2 & 0x0F) + 3;
            chunk_offset = ((cmd2 & 0xF0) << 4) | cmd1;

            for ( ; chunk_length > 0 ; chunk_length--) {
                /* Copy historical data to output AND current ring pos */
                *pos++ = ring[chunk_offset];
                ring[ring_pos] = ring[chunk_offset];

                /* Update counters */
                chunk_offset = (chunk_offset + 1) % 0x1000;
                ring_pos = (ring_pos + 1) % 0x1000;
                length--;
            }
        }

        /* Get next control bit */
        control_word >>= 1;
    }

    return out;
}

static void readfile(const char *filename, u8_t **data, long *nbytes)
{
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (f == NULL) abort();

    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    *nbytes = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    *data = malloc(*nbytes);
    fread(*data, *nbytes, 1, f);

    fclose(f);
}

void put8(FILE *f, unsigned char val)
{
    fwrite(&val, 1, 1, f);
}

void put16(FILE *f, unsigned short val)
{
    fwrite(&val, 2, 1, f);
}

void split_images(const char *in_dir, const char *out_dir, 
    struct image *images, int nimages)
{
    struct clip *clips;
    char filename[512];
    long nbytes;
    u8_t *data;
    char *name;
    FILE *f;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    /* Read file and get TOC */
    sprintf(filename, "%s/system.idx", in_dir);
    readfile(filename, &data, &nbytes);
    clips = (struct clip *) (data + 0x01BC);
    name = (char *) (data + 8 + *((long *) data));

    /* Guess how many clips there are with a heuristic */
    for (i = 0 ; clips[i].w != 0 && clips[i].h != 0 ; i++) {
        sprintf(filename, "%s/%s.tga", out_dir, name);
        name += strlen(name) + 3;

        f = fopen(filename, "wb");
        if (f == NULL) abort();

        /* Locate the correct source image */
        j = 0;
        while (clips[i].y > images[j].height) {
            clips[i].y -= images[j].height;
            j++;
        }

        /* Write header */
        put8(f, 0); put8(f, 0); put8(f, 2);
        put16(f, 0); put16(f, 0); put8(f, 0);
        put16(f, 0); put16(f, 0); put16(f, clips[i].w); put16(f, clips[i].h);
        put8(f, 32); put8(f, 32);

        /* Write scanlines */
        for (k = 0 ; k < clips[i].h ; k++) {
            if (clips[i].y == images[j].height) {
                clips[i].y = 0;
                j++;
            }

            fwrite(images[j].planes + ((images[j].width * clips[i].y) +
                clips[i].x) * 4, clips[i].w, 4, f);
            clips[i].y++;
        }

        /* Close output file */
        fclose(f);
    }

    /* Cleanup */
    free(data);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *in_dir;
    char *out_dir;

    struct image images[32];
    char filename[256];
    unsigned int i;
    long filesize;
    u8_t *lzss, *gc;
    size_t out_sz;
    FILE *f;

    /* Usage */
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [indir] [outdir]\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Setup */
    memset(images, 0, sizeof(images));
    in_dir = argv[1];
    out_dir = argv[2];

    for (i = 0 ; i < 32 ; i++) {
        /* Open 0.gcz, 1.gcz etc ... */
        sprintf(filename, "%s/%d.gcz", in_dir, i);
        f = fopen(filename, "rb");
        if (f == NULL) break;

        /* Read entire file */
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        filesize = ftell(f);
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

        fprintf(stderr, "%s: fread", filename);
        lzss = malloc(filesize);
        fread(lzss, filesize, 1, f);
        fclose(f);

        /* Decompress */
        fprintf(stderr, "(OK) expand_lzss");
        gc = expand_lzss(lzss, &out_sz);
        free(lzss);

        /* Unpack GC to 32-bit RGBA */
        fprintf(stderr, "(OK) unpack_gc");
        unpack_gc(&images[i], gc, out_sz);
        free(gc);

        fprintf(stderr, "(OK)\n");
    }

    /* Sanity check */
    if (i == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No GCZ files found\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Emit pile of TGAs */
    fprintf(stderr, "split_images");
    split_images(in_dir, out_dir, images, i);
    fprintf(stderr, "(OK)\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with the code that could be causing this? The code is unaltered save for `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` being added to the code before the `#include` headers and having the program compiled as C.

Comment: Anything. What files did you try it on

Comment: There is explicit abort for file opening failed. The target directory must exist

Comment: Since you seem to know what "debug" is, please single step through your program to find the place where the `abort()` is called. Then you probably know what is wrong.

Comment: the only place that calls `abort()` is if the code is unable to open a file.  This is done in the function:  `readfile()`  The file name is from a parameter, passed from  a 'path'/system.idx that was generated in the function: `split_images()`   Where the 'path' is from the first parameter when executing the program.   The OP needs to post exactly how the program was executed and the relevant part of the directory indicated by that first command line parameter.

Comment: The files in that case are .gcz files (graphical texture files used by Konami's Firebeat arcade system) that are read by the system and shown on-screen as 2D raster graphics. The files I used came from the ParaParaParadise (1.0) CD-ROM data disc and had the .gcz files in various folders. In the BG folder, there are several folders containing a few .GCZ files (depends on how many animations are in the BG sequence) followed by INDEX.IDX. The command for gcz2tga is `gcz2tga [indir] [outdir]`. (1/2)

Comment: (2/?) When I tried to input this command into Command Prompt:

`gcz2tga C:\Users\Harrison\Documents\VOL_20000806034542\BG\EURO_1 "C:\Users\Harrison\Documents\gcz2tga output"

C:\Users\Harrison\Documents\VOL_20000806034542\BG\EURO_1/0.gcz: fread(OK) expand_lzss(OK) unpack_gc(1024x1024)(OK)
C:\Users\Harrison\Documents\VOL_20000806034542\BG\EURO_1/1.gcz: fread(OK) expand_lzss(OK) unpack_gc(1024x1024)(OK)
C:\Users\Harrison\Documents\VOL_20000806034542\BG\EURO_1/2.gcz: fread(OK) expand_lzss(OK) unpack_gc(1024x384)(OK)
split_images`

Comment: (3/3) When it gets to `split_images` that's when it crashes and `abort()` is called. I also compiled it as Debug, if that helps.